# Trying to use the outcome of first method in second method java

Tags: java, arraylist, methods

I am trying to learn how can I use the outcome of one method in another method.

In example below it creates an `ArrayList` of integers from 1 to 50 and then takes an absolute value of random two values from the `ArrayList` of integers, then adds this absolute value to the list (named `boardIntegers`), but removes the selected random two numbers.

This is repeated 49 times.

I have solved it by creating one method and then calling that method from main method.

Can I solve by creating two methods, for example one for creating the list `boardIntegers` and the other for updating `boardIntegers`?

```
package ProblemAllocated;  

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Board {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UpdateBoard();
        //method2();
    }
    
    public static void UpdateBoard() { 
        int a;
        int b;
        int AbsC;
        ArrayList <Integer>boardIntegers = new ArrayList<>();
        Random fromBoard = new Random();

        for (int i = 1; i < 51; i++) {
            boardIntegers.add(i);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            a = fromBoard.nextInt((boardIntegers.size()));
            b = fromBoard.nextInt((boardIntegers.size()));
            AbsC = Math.abs(b - a);
            boardIntegers.add(AbsC);
            boardIntegers.remove(a);
            boardIntegers.remove(b);
            System.out.println("The remaining integers after executing " 
                + i + " times are " + boardIntegers 
                + " and size of List is " + boardIntegers.size()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can--method can return whatever you want (for example, "nextInt" returns an integer).

Comment: Aside note: you are calculating the difference between random indexes `a` and `b` -- not between the values at these indexes: `int va = boardIntegers.get(a); int vb = boardIntegers.get(b); AbsC = Math.abs(va - vb);`

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Sorry, misunderstood. As Dave Newton is trying to say, your first method
could create the collection, and return it, which in turn can be passed on to the next method that updates it.

E.g.

```
int boardSize = 50;
ArrayList<Integer> board = createBoard(boardSize);
updateBoard(board);
```

Hope you understand, and you'll have to implement the methods yourself. :-)

Side note. The variable `board` is passed as value. This means the reference to the object is copied and passed, not the object itself. So if you try to overwrite `board` inside `updateBoard` you will overwrite the copied reference, with a another reference pointing to another object, and not the original reference, nor the original object. But the copied reference points to the original object, which means calling methods using the copied referenced, will call methods on the original object and thus impact the original object, e.g. `board.remove(a)` inside `updateBoard`, will change the the `board` object from `main`.

**END EDIT**

Yes - you can either create a local variable in main, and pass it as a parameter to each method, or create a global variable which you use in both methods.

Hope it makes sense. :-)

Answer (score 0):

## Yes, use multiple smaller methods

> Can I solve by creating two methods, for example one for creating the list boardIntegers and the other for updating boardIntegers?

Yes, you can. And you should. Better to have smaller chunks of code with a specific narrow purpose, segregated into well-named methods.

You will see in the code below that we broke out your code into two principal methods:

- a constructor
- a method named `randomize`

## OOP

I think the bigger picture you are missing is [object-oriented programming (OOP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).

Your `Board` class should represent a board, describing a board from real life. A board has characteristics/attributes, in your case here, a size and set of integers (which I am guessing represents slots or positions on the board). So your class should represent those attributes as [*state*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_(computer_science)), as member field variables.

```java
public class Board
{
    // Member fields.
    final private int boardSize;
    final private List < Integer > slots;
…
```

Get the basics of your board’s state ready in a constructor. Generally best to keep your constructor as short and as simple as possible. The goal is to do the least necessary to leave the object in a coherent state.

In our case here, perhaps the constructor should just establish the slots with the default 1, 2, 3, … sequencing. Our constructor takes one parameter, the size (50), as that is likely to be the one aspect of the board you are likely to change (my assumption).

```java
// Constructor
public Board ( final int boardSize )
{
    this.boardSize = boardSize;
    this.slots = new ArrayList <>( this.boardSize );
    // Populate the slots with sequential numbers, one through count of slots.
    for ( int nthSlot = 1 ; nthSlot <= this.boardSize ; nthSlot++ )
    {
        this.slots.add( nthSlot );
    }
    // Or more briefly, using streams:
    // this.slots = new ArrayList <>( IntStream.rangeClosed( 1 , this.boardSize ).boxed().toList() );
}
```

Your goal is to randomize the slots of the board. So create a method `randomize` to do that work.

I question the logic of your code for the randomizing, but that code is not relevant to the point of your Question. So let’s skip that code, and simply replace each slot’s value with the result of a call to [`ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextInt(int)).

```java
private void randomize ( )
{
    for ( int index = 0 ; index < this.boardSize ; index++ )
    {
        int absC = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( 1_000 );
        this.slots.set( index , absC );
    }
}
```

We need a way to examine our board object. So we add another method, this one named `report`.

```java
private void report ( )
{
    System.out.println( "this.slots = " + this.slots + " at " + Instant.now() );
}
```

To get back to the point of your question, notice how **the state of the object** (the member fields `boardSize` & `slots`) **is shared** between the various methods. Yes, methods could instead package their results as a return value. But in this case, all the methods are focused on working on this one board object. So we let those methods share access to the member fields. We let those the `Board` methods directly manipulate the `Board` object’s fields (state).

Also notice that we mark the member fields `private` to deny access by outside code. Only methods on `Board` class should be manipulating the state of a `Board` object (generally). Methods on other classes should be denied access (generally).

The choreographer to make our objects dance is the `main` method.

```java
public static void main ( String[] args )
{
    Board board = new Board( 50 );
    board.report();
    
    board.randomize();
    board.report();
}
```

Pull all that code together.

```java
package work.basil.game;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Board
{
    // Member fields.
    final private int boardSize;
    final private List < Integer > slots;

    // Constructor
    public Board ( final int boardSize )
    {
        this.boardSize = boardSize;
        this.slots = new ArrayList <>( this.boardSize );
        // Populate the slots with sequential numbers, one through count of slots.
        for ( int nthSlot = 1 ; nthSlot <= this.boardSize ; nthSlot++ )
        {
            this.slots.add( nthSlot );
        }
        // Or more briefly, using streams.
        // this.slots = new ArrayList <>( IntStream.rangeClosed( 1 , this.boardSize ).boxed().toList() );
    }

    // Logic

    private void randomize ( )
    {
        for ( int index = 0 ; index < this.boardSize ; index++ )
        {
            int absC = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( 1_000 );
            this.slots.set( index , absC );
        }
    }

    private void report ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "this.slots = " + this.slots + " at " + Instant.now() );
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        Board board = new Board( 50 );
        board.report();

        board.randomize();
        board.report();
    }
}
```

When run.

> this.slots = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50] at 2021-12-17T23:09:04.872711Z
>
> this.slots = [395, 335, 46, 691, 7, 799, 52, 354, 972, 127, 102, 767, 588, 126, 178, 762, 437, 895, 460, 222, 439, 316, 150, 445, 963, 878, 776, 820, 263, 457, 259, 513, 639, 102, 176, 828, 738, 866, 6, 540, 996, 511, 576, 52, 85, 833, 889, 498, 555, 925] at 2021-12-17T23:09:04.884395Z

By the way, notice the naming in the code here. Following the Java naming conventions makes code easier to read. For example, variables and methods both start with a lowercase letter. So, `int AbsC;` should be `int absC;`. And `UpdateBoard()` should be `updateBoard()`.

### OOP with multiple methods makes code easier to comprehend

Hopefully you can see how using multiple methods and OOP makes this code much easier to read and comprehend. OOP was invented to make life easier for human programmers, not for the benefit of computer machines.

- A programmer looking at this class can glance at the member fields to see the main idea of the class: Holding a certain number of slots.
- Then a glance at the constructor reveals the nature of the slots, defaulting to a series of numbers.
- And then looking at the `main` shows how our intention is to alter the board by randomizing the values of those slots.

Tip: [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)s provide a “structure” panel to expose and navigate these methods, for quick review by a programmer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that explains a lot however you missed a point that it should remove two selected values from the board  after adding the absolute value to the original board. In the given example we are trying to understand how the second method can update the object created in first method. You have been great help already.

Comment: @Shawzz As I mentioned, that part of your code does not make sense. For one thing, after you remove an element by index `a`, you remove another element by index `b` — but that second index may no longer be valid as the elements have shifted their position from the first deletion. Furthermore, the goal of that operation is not clear from your prose. And also, the aspect of manipulating the list *is* covered here. I showed how you have access to `this.slots` from within the `randomize` method. If you can call `List#set` there, then you can call any other `List` method including `add` & `remove`.